# I have installed SSL on webuzo on one of my moodle pages but it is not working

Tags: ssl, certificate, moodle

The Following page is not working after installing the SSl certificate.
I am using WEBUZO Webuzo Panel for my Moodle site. please help me. https://www.edtechglobal.net%22/

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are using the wrong url.

This works for me:

https://www.edtechglobal.net/moodle/